# pass function name as parameter to another function and call it in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a function name and its parameters as parameter and call it

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    runfn(getUserName,paramValue);
});

function runfn(fnName,param){
    fnName(param);
};

function getUserName(userId){
    alert(userId);
};
```

Feel free to edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96mhqLfp/)

i want to call function with parameters using this method

Comment: Pass the name, not a string containing the name.

Comment: You should probably specify some sort of use case for this, because a lot of people are missing that you want to include parameters in your function call. There are a number of ways you could do that, of course, but I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just use a standard function callback like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/96mhqLfp/3/).

Answer (score 3):

If you want that you might need to use the [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)(). Be aware that this has potential security issues with it. You can also just call the function on the global window object: `window[fnName]();`

Additionally, in your case, you can also just pass the reference to the function. Meaning, do not specify the function name as a string, but just as a function.

```
callMe(functionToCall);

function callMe(fn){
    fn();
}

function functionToCall(){
    alert('Called!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to pass it as function name and not as string

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/96mhqLfp/1/)**

Just a sample code where changes needed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("loaded");
    runfn(test);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Just pass parameter in the phase where you are calling the function as below:

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/96mhqLfp/6/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("loaded");
    runfn(test);
});

function runfn(fnName){
    alert(fnName);
    fnName('name');
};

function test(name){
     alert(name);
};
```

Comment: thanks
how can i pass value to that function?